# Git no branch + operation timed out

Tags: git

I attempted to merge a branch with `main`, but the merge failed. Now, on my Mac, I have a series of changed files (that don't actually contain any changes) on no branch. Attempting to switch back to the branch I was working on with `git checkout <branch>` produces the error `error: the following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:` and then the list of those files. However, any attempt to commit or discard the files produces the following error:
`fatal: mmap failed: Operation timed out`.

I'm not sure what to do to get back onto the branch I was working on.

Comment: Does `git checkout -f <branch>` yield any different results? FYI it will force overwrite files when you checkout the branch, so it will wipe out uncommitted changes in your local directory.

Comment: Same error: fatal: mmap failed: Operation timed out

Comment: If nothing is currently staged, can you post the output of `git add -A -v`? Also, try `git gc` followed by `git checkout -f <branch>`.

Comment: https://ibb.co/6X7HpgD still getting the same error.

Comment: This is weird; mmap does not list ETIMEDOUT as a possible error in the first place, and it does not make sense either. (This points to some kind of OS bug.)

Comment: @anorlondo Just curious, how did you install git and what version of git are you running (`git --version`)? The git download page lists several third party ways to install git, some of which might be out of date. Assuming @torek is correct in it being an OS bug, can you provide some OS-related information such as the OS version, kernel version (`uname -r`)?

Comment: It may well be an issue with macOS,  since I'm not having the same problem on my Windows laptop. I installed git via the terminal with homebrew, and I believe I'm running the latest versions of both git and macOS, but I'll provide you with the rest of the info you've asked for once I get home.

Comment: Also, can you check activity monitor and see if any active processes are consuming a large amount of RAM?

Comment: I'm running git version 2.37.1. I'm running kernel 21.5.0. Here's a screenshot of memory usage: https://ibb.co/LtwKRpk. The process using the most memory is MS PowerPoint, at ~400mb.

Comment: You might try using `--no-progress`, which has Git disable its use of the "alarm clock" signals to display progress indicators. mmap() is not supposed to be interrupted by these signals, but [macOS has in the past had bugs where various nominally-un-interruptable syscalls were in fact interrupted](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9dd64cb4d310986dd7b8ca7fff92f9b61e0bd21a/Documentation/RelNotes/2.31.0.txt#L227-L230), and Git has a few workarounds in the source code for that. The Git guys might need to add one for mmap() as well.