# git fsck shows fatal: mmap failed: Operation timed out

Tags: git, github-desktop

Suddenly some of my git repos are failing with `fatal: mmap failed: Operation timed out` on executing git cli commands.

I was using github desktop , have been working on multiple branches on the repos. Stashed changes and moved between the branches. Suddenly one day i see github desktop complains with `Cannot find repository , it was last seen at` .

So, i executed the git cli commands and it seems the git repos got corrupted.

Any way to come out of this problem.

Answer (score 2):

This was [seen before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73009021/6309), mostly related to an OS-specific issue (like [interrupted syscall](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9dd64cb4d310986dd7b8ca7fff92f9b61e0bd21a/Documentation/RelNotes/2.31.0.txt#L227-L230) on MacOS for instance)

GitHub Desktop [includes its own Git](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/15160#issuecomment-1225386551), so try first to:

- upgrade Git (outside of GitHub Desktop) to its latest version
- check if the issue persists then (again, using that latest Git version, from a shell outside GitHub Desktop)
- uninstall/reinstall GitHub Desktop.

If the issue persists, check if cloning the repository (in a separate folder) and importing your work from your previous local folder would be an acceptable workaround.

Comment: thanks for the answer...first 3 steps did not work...will try cloning the repo again but then this would lose all the stashes and local changes...

Comment: @saurav You can clone it in another folder, outside your first clone. From there, you can import your work in progress from the first cloned repository to the second clone.